# The meaning of "Well, he sure made"

Tags: sentence-meaning

A and B borrowed C's rafts long time ago, and now A asks B if B knew C well.

> **B:** I don't know a lot about him, but I know he build good houses and he also...
>
> **A:** Well, ***he sure made*** good rafts.

Does A mean *he/she is not really sure about other things B mentioned, but he is at least sure about that C made good rafts*?

Comment: Yes, because A seems to know less about C than B does.

Comment: Taken in isolation, A's use of the word ***sure*** merely emphasizes that the speaker is *certain, sure* of what he's saying (that C *definitely* makes good rafts). In any given context it's possible that introductory ***Well*** implies the speaker either disagrees or cannot establish the truth of whatever was said previously, but it might equally be intended to *amplify and agree with* a prior assertion. In short, you can't assign a definite meaning to A's statement - it depends on pragmatic assumptions suitable to the context (but these "noise words" may actually mean nothing in particular).

Answer (score 1):

The expression

> he sure made *something*

means he did a really good job of doing *something*; "really" could be interchanged with "sure".

> he sure made good rafts
>   *he really made good rafts*
>
> he sure made a fool of himself
>   he sure made an ass of himself
>   *he (did something) to make himself look really stupid*

In your example, "well" is used as an intensifier to stress a point.

Of course, context and intonation matter might matter a lot in signifying whether the expression is being used genuinely or sarcastically.